# FileNotFoundException for a valid file using FileInputStream

Tags: java, io, filenotfoundexception

When I write an `FileInputStream`, while I have the valid file, it throws a FileNotFoundException.
I used this:

```
package io;
import java.io.*;
public class implementIo {
    public static int i;
    public static FileOutputStream output;
    public static FileInputStream input;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
                output = new FileOutputStream("writeModification.txt");
            input = new FileInputStream("modification.txt");
            do {
        i = input.read();
        if(i != -1) output.write(i);
        }while(i != -1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception caught " + e);
    } finally {
        try {
            if(output == null) input.close();
        }catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException caught: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

}

While I had a two separate files named *"modification.txt"* and *"printModification.txt"* in the same package folder, yet the system threw a `FileNotFoundException`. Please help!

Comment: Show full stack trace output

Comment: the files will be searched in the current working directory, the one where java is started or which is set in the IDE - most certainly not the package folder. You can use something like `System.out.println(new File("modification.txt").getAbsolutePath());` to see where the file is searched

Comment: Why are you editing your post but not putting in the  stack trace as requested?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is because the FileInputStream doesn't provide the file creation during initialization like `new FileOutputStream()` does. So if these have been said, we can see one interesting thing to keep in mind: the **modification.txt** will be created every time when you initialize the `FileOutputStream` (and **won't** be overwritten) and this is why most probably your code breaks at the `new FileInputStream()` line.

How can you handle your exception? 
You either create your file before executing the code( manually with `New` -> `Text Document` etc. ) or modify your code and make use of `File` class :

```
File file = new File("modification.txt");
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
        input = new FileInputStream(file);
        //your code here - output etc.
```

Your code still doesn't work even if you have the files created in the same package folder? It's because the default path that your streams are looking for your files is the current working directory. Here is an example :

```
myproject
   |___src
   |    |___main
   |          |___java
   |                |___io
   |                     |___implementIo
   |___writeModification.txt
   |___modification.txt
```

This is the correct structure if you want to use the streams like you did (with just a simple file name in stream constructor argument). But if your files are not there, you have to specify the absolute path. Here is an example :

```
 myproject
   |___src
        |___main
              |___java
                    |___io
                         |___implementIo
                         |___writeModification.txt
                         |___modification.txt
```

And the correct way to access the files is this:

```
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("C://myproject//src//main//java//io//modification.txt");
```

Same for the output stream. (Please modify the path with your correct file location)

Comment: `modification.txt` *will* be overwritten every time you call `new FileOutputStream("modification.txt")`, and creating an empty input file prior to `new FileInputStream(...)` is completely pointless. The 'default path that your streams are looking for your files' is *not* the 'project directory' but the current working directory. Answer is completely incorrect.

Comment: I get your point why it would be completly pointless, but I was thinking that maybe the OP wants to modify the file before he reads something. And I wanted to say current working directory too, not project directory, thank you for your observation.

Comment: You can't modify a file that doesn't exist. If the OP wants to put some content into a *new* file before reading it, let him do so, and when he calls `new FileOuputStream()` in the process of doing so, that file will get created: although why he needs a file at all in such a case remains a mystery. `File.createNewFile()` has few correct uses, and this isn't one of them.

Comment: And there is nothing 'correct' about providing a full path name to open a file, especially when that path refers directly to a specific user's directory structure on a specific computer. There is no reason why he can't continue to use a relative path name, as long as he understands what it is relative to.

Comment: Ok, thank you for making me understand why my answer was not correct.